# Minimise repetition of bindings in view

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular, as will probably become apparent!

I've created a view with a few tables of data to show users different statistics.  A simple example would be:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <table class="percs">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Stat Name</td>
                <td>Stat Value</td>
                <td>Stat bar</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Stat 1</td>
                <td>{{ statPercs.stat1 }}</td>
                <td><uib-progressbar value="statPercs.stat1"></uib-progressbar></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stat 2</td>
                <td>{{ statPercs.stat2 }}</td>
                <td><uib-progressbar value="statPercs.stat2"></uib-progressbar></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using the progressbar just for a small visual representation of the data.  However if my understanding so far is correct, although each row in the table only references one value it will incur 2 $$watchers by being referenced in 2 separate tags.

Is it possible to achieve this with just one binding per value (i.e. "statPercs.stat1", "statPercs.stat2", etc) but still be able to re-use that value in multiple columns of the table?

Or even better still, one binding for the object itself (i.e. "statPercs") and still be able to use the values contained in that object in multiple places in the table?

Comment: You need to use Directive concept .. which i reusable angular deals it self https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_custom_directives.htm

Comment: You're using angular as documented. That creates watchers, and it's expected because that is how angular works. You shouldn't try to optimize anything if you don't have any performance problem (and I bet you don't have any). 2 watchers is nothing. Start asking yourself questions when you have a performance, and see that you have more than 2000/3000 or so.

Comment: @N.V.Prasad I know about custom directives but I guess I'm not clear on how to use them to eliminate those multiple bindings.  Would I simply create local variables within the directive based on the values of the scope objects and re-use them, rather than using several {{}} bindings to the scope object itself?

Comment: @JBNizet unfortunately my example was a simplified one.  I have several tables, most with at least 10 rows and some with up to 5 columns.  Throw in a few ngClass and ngShow directives along with a menu tree based on ngRepeat and it results in a watcher count of around 5000!  That's why I decided to take a step back and figure out what I had done wrong.